# How can I safely downcast this?

Tags: c++, xcode, casting, downcast

Edit: I got this to work (see in answers below) in VS2012, but it still doesn't properly downcast in Xcode.

I am trying to downcast from an unsigned long to an int in C++, but data loss seems inevitable:

```
unsigned long bigInt= randomBigNumber;
int x = 2;
```

I then pass a big number to a function that accepts signed ints:

```
void myFunc(bigInt/(ULONG_MAX/x));
```

If randomBigNumber is a repeated random number -- such as in a for-loop -- I figure I should get a relatively evenly distributed number of ones and zeros, but I am only getting zeros.

How can I downcast this so as to get some ones?

Thanks.

Comment: in case x is 2 `bigNumber > (ULONG_MAX/x)`

Comment: Right, Bryan. My problem was the way I was typing the code. I forgot to mention I was actually passing that number into a function that took a signed int (which is a big deal).

Answer (score 1):

Re

> **”** I am only getting zeros

That’s because you’re dividing by a pretty big number. If the range of the random number generator is less than that big number, you can only get zeroes.

---

Re

> **”** How can I downcast this so as to get some ones?

You can do

```
myFunc(bigInt % 2);
```

There is however an impact on randomness. At least of old the least significant bits of a pseudo-random number were likely to be very much less than perfectly random, due to imperfect generators. So except for efficiency you might be better off doing e.g.

```
myFunc((bigInt / 8) % 2);
```

if you are interested in nice randomness. It all depends on the generator of course. And there are other more elaborate techniques for improving randomness.

Answer (score 0):

I figured one way:

```
unsigned long bigInt = randomBigNumber;
unsigned long x = ULONG_MAX / 2;
myFunc(bigInt / x);
```

That worked for me. I was able to generate zero and ones.
Note: I can only get this to work in VS2012, but not Xcode. Why?

Comment: Storing the value `ULONG_MAX / 2` in a variable should not have any effect; the expressions do the exact same.